# Copying dynamically copied DLL's from bin folder during publish

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am using dependency injection in my application, and the dll's used for contract implementations are copied to my applications bin folder via a post build event on the projects that implement my contracts. I have done it this way so I do not have to reference these projects and I am using convention over configuration with class names etc.

However, when I publish the application the dll's are not being copies as part of the publish. Anyone know a way around this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a Post Build event, include the dll as part of the Project. In your Solutions Explorer, right click on the dll, choose properties and set "Build Actions" to "Copy if Newer". The dll will always be included while Publishing.

Comment: I do know how to add a reference - the problem with this when using dependency injection and IOC is that I do not want my main application project to know anything about who or what is implementing contracts it relies upon, using the post build event means at runtime the DI lib I am using can scan the application bin folder and find matching classes for the contracts required

Comment: Build Events do not go well with MSBuild, they are handled by the Visual Studio IDE. If you plan to automate your builds the Build Events don't kick in automatically. The best way to handle your situation is open your project file in text mode and add a 
  <Target Name="BeforePublish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="yourSourcePath\yourfile" DestinationFiles="publishPath\yourfile">
  </Target>

Comment: Even though this doesn't exactly solve my problem it's what I ended up doing so marked as answer